# In Xamarin.Forms, how to read a list of assets from a project's folder?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do an app that reproduce some audio tracks. The tracks are inside a directory "Music" and I cannot asume they are fixed, hence I cannot read them 1 by 1 using the file's name.

Solution directory tree:

```
MySolution/

  MyApp/
    Music/
      track01
      track02
      ...
    App.xaml
    MyAppPage.xaml   

  MyApp.Droid/
    ...   

  MyApp.iOS/
    ...
```

What I need to achieve is something like this:

**MyAppPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyAppPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyAppPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var files = Directory.GetFiles("./Music");
            musicListView.ItemsSource = files;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyAppPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyAppPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <ListView x:Name="musicListView" />

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

I also tried with:

```
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(currentDir, "Music"));
```

But current dir is just "/". I don't know if I am simply messing with the paths or if Xamarin does not allow this kind of operations. If that's the case, is there any standard approach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Mmm wonna get a list?

```
    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var MyAssemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name; //now this is for the future
    //if you want acces files by a generated name would be:
    // MyAssemblyName + ".Music."+filename
    //anyway now we are building the whole list:
    var MusicFiles = new List<string>(); //todo change to your music class 
    foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
    {
        if (res.Contains(".track"))
        {
            MusicFiles.Add(res);
        }
    }
```

Do not forget to include files as Embedded Resource (check files properties).

More info here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/

Answer (score 1):

Check the Saving and Loading Files section of this document on [handling files in Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/). You may need to handle this differently on different platforms. The article details how to create an interface for use in your PCL which you then implement on each platform to deal with the specifics of that platform:

> Because Xamarin.Forms runs on multiple platforms, each with its own filesystem, there is no single approach for loading and saving files

[Here is an article describing how to load a bundled file in iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/file_system/load_a_file/).

There's also [some good chat on this thread for reading files bundled with your app](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12362/json-net-how-do-i-load-a-file-from-the-solution) (again in iOS):

```
var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("FileName", "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out PCLStorage on Nuget. It will allow you to save and retrieve files in the App's own storage space.