# How to retrieve list of files from the local application folder which is in Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have one folder "MyFolder" created in my Xamarin.Forms project and there are few files inside that folder. How can I retrieve all the files which are in that folder?

I tried below code but it's giving exception that Folder does not exist.

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\MyFolder"))
 {

 }
```

Even the below code is giving the same error.

```
string folderPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MyFolder");

 foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
 {

 }
```

Comment: The `Path.Combine(..)` method could help to retrieve the files saved on each platform. To access the local files in PCL, try to make the files **Embedded** as **Resources**. Set **Build Action** of the file to **EmbeddedResource**, then use the `GetManifestResourceStream` method to access the embedded file. Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#loading-files-embedded-as-resources

Comment: @y3z1 I don't want to read the content of the file. What I am looking for is to get a list of filenames that are located in my local project folder.

Comment: To get the list of the filenames, try to use `GetManifestResourceNames` to get the resources. Then detect the resource name to get the related file name in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to retrieve list of files from the local application folder which is in Xamarin.Forms project?

Try to traverse the resources in the assembly of the app to detect if the resource name contains 'MyFolder'. You could get the resources using `GetManifestResourceNames` method.

Don't forget to set the **Build Action** of all  the files in the folder to **EmbeddedResource**.

Check the code:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var list = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

List<string> fileList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item.Contains("MyFolder"))
    {
        fileList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185054/11083277