# Get all objects from a folder in Xamarin project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin. Questions are ripe for which I have not found the answers in Google.

1. Can I get a specific project folder? (For example, CuteAnimals).
2. Is it possible to get all objects from a specific project folder? (For example, images from the CuteAnimals folder).

[My folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlJ1Q.png)

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179234/in-xamarin-forms-how-to-read-a-list-of-assets-from-a-projects-folder) will answer your question. Xamarin.Forms code runs on multiple platforms - each of which has its own filesystem. Previously, this meant that reading and writing files was most easily performed using the native file APIs on each platform. Alternatively, [embedded resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows) are a simpler solution to distribute data files with an app.

Comment: @Ranjit ,thanks for the answer! What then is the cross-platform nature of Xamarin, if I cannot embed the data I need into the program?

Comment: @padalchik About xamarin, you can take a look: [What is Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin)